# How to find out if a value of an array shows up more then once

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out if a value of an array shows up more then once and if it does then I need to know how many duplicates there is.

For example I have an array that looks like this

```
array:5 [
  0 => "PR001"
  1 => "PR002"
  2 => "PR002"
  3 => "PR003"
  4 => "PR004"
]
```

I would like to do something like this

```
if($array[$productCode] > 2)
{
    echo 'this has duplicates';
}else{
    echo 'this has no duplicates';
}
```

My code is like this

```
$productArr = [];
foreach($products as $productCode => $product)
{
    $productArr = $productCode;
}
```

My `$productArr` prints out the array above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$values = array_count_values(['PR001', 'PR002', 'PR002', 'PR003']);
if (1 < $values['PR002']) {
    echo 'Value is not unique';
}
```

Comment: When I try to use your suggestion and make it work for my code I get this error. `array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!
`

Comment: So this means that your array stores not ints and not strings.

Comment: I've edited my question with what I would like to do. Maybe that would help.

Comment: That wouldn't. Message clearly tells you that in your array there;re some other values, not ints, not strings, Maybe these are subarrays or whatever. So `var_dump()` your data and show.

Comment: sorry the issue was that my array and a null value

Comment: Glad, you solved your problem)